# If $f\in C^{\alpha}([a,b])$, $f\geq0$ and $0<p<1$, is it true $f^p\in C^{\beta}([a,b])$ for some $0<\beta<1$?

Tags: real-analysis, holder-spaces

Let $f\in C^{\alpha}([a,b])$ and $f\geq0$, where $C^{\alpha}$ denotes the $\alpha$-Hölder space.

If $p\geq1$, then $f^p\in C^{\alpha}([a,b])$, by the mean value theorem applied to $g(x)=x^p$. Indeed, $f^p(x)-f^p(y)=g(f(x))-g(f(y))=p\,\xi_{x,y}^{p-1}(f(x)-f(y))$, with $\xi_{x,y}\in [f(x),f(y)]$, and since $f$ is bounded, say by $M>0$, then $\xi_{x,y}\leq M$, so $|f^p(x)-f^p(y)|\leq C|f(x)-f(y)|$.

What about $0<p<1$? In such a case, $\xi_{x,y}^{p-1}$ may not be bounded, as it can go to $0$. Thus, do we have $f^p\in C^{\beta}([a,b])$ for some $0<\beta<1$?

Comment: If you consider $f(x) = x^\alpha$, $x\in [0,1]$, then $f\in C^\alpha([0,1])$. On the other hand, if $0<p<1$, $f^p \not\in C^\alpha$. (Nevertheless, $f^p\in C^{\alpha p}$.)

Comment: @Rigel So is it possible $f^p\notin C^{\beta}([a,b])$ for any $\beta\in(0,1)$? I edited the question, as I had not thought about that more general question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start from the following well-known inequality (here $p \in (0,1)$):
$$
| x^p - y^p| \leq |x-y|^p\qquad
\forall x,y \geq 0.
$$
If $f$ is a non-negative $\alpha$-Holder function and $p\in (0,1)$, we get
$$
|f(x)^p - f(y)^p|\leq |f(x) - f(y)|^p \leq C |x-y|^{\alpha p},
$$
hence $f\in C^{\alpha p}$.